# Polytopes whose intersections have few vertices

Tags: convex-polytopes

This is related to one that I asked earlier:

[The intersection of two $l_1$ balls](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201762/the-intersection-of-two-l-1-balls)

My question:  are there any general classes of polytopes $P_1,P_2\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $P_1$ has few vertices, $P_2$ has few vertices, and $P_1\cap P_2$ has few vertices?
(in my particular problem, $P_1$ is a unit ball in the $l_1$ norm, but I am interested in this question more generally)

Comment: The unit ball is not a polytope.

Comment: Meant to say "unit ball in $l_1$", how embarassing...

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow!  Perhaps they will make a "Human" badge for "edit on first post".  Gerhard "Has Plenty Of Badges Already" Paseman, 2015.04.02

Comment: You question suggests this (easier) one: What is the maximum number of vertices of an intersection of two simplices in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @JenniferGao: no problem. It's a nice question.

Comment: An intersection of two simplices in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has at most $2n+2$ facets. By the Upper Bound Theorem for polytopes, the number of vertices is at most $2\sum_{i=0}^{(n-1)/2}{n+i+1\choose i}$ if $n$ is odd, and $2\sum_{i=0}^{\frac n2-1}{n+i+1\choose i} + {\frac{3n}{2}+1\choose \frac n2}$ if $n$ is even. I don't know how close one can come to achieving these bounds.

Comment: You can realize a combinatorial hypercube as the intersection of two simplices ; this is an example with exponentially many vertices